# Can't scrape robots in python using beautifulsoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I managed to get the soup and the html of the webpage, but for some reason can't find the `robots tag` even though I can find it when scraping in other languages.

Example:

```
headers = {
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87  Safari/537.36',
        'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,/;q=0.8', 
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 
    }

res=requests.get('http://{}'.format("radverdirect.com"), headers=headers, allow_redirects = True)
number= str(res.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

x=soup.find('meta', attrs={'name':'robots'})
out=x.get("content", None)  
out
```

This site returns to me **noodp** in other languages but here I can't find this tag.  Why and how do I fix it?

Comment: I think you should split all your questions in differents threads. And your questions do not concern spark at all.

Comment: the first two are related. I can spilt the third do you know the solution? i didnt say it has to do with spark